# Writing Data to an HDF5 File Using H5Py Results in an Empty File

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

I'm working on converting a large database for storage in an HDF5 file.  To get familiar with H5Py (version 3.2.1) and HDF5, I read the [docs for H5Py](https://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/index.html) and wrote a small script that stores random data in an HDF5 file, shown below.

```
import h5py
import numpy as np


def main():
    f = h5py.File('testFile.hdf5', 'w')
    simBigData = np.random.randint(50, size=(24, 6), dtype=np.int32)
    simSmallData = np.random.randint(50, size=(8, 6), dtype=np.int32)
    simOut = np.random.randint(50, size=(8, 6), dtype=np.int32)
    grp = f.create_group('testGroup')
    dsBigData = grp.create_dataset('bigData', data=simBigData)
    dsSmallData = grp.create_dataset('smallData', data=simSmallData)
    dsOut = grp.create_dataset('out', data=simOut)
    print('HDF5 Data')
    print(f['testGroup/bigData'])
    print(f['testGroup/smallData'])
    print(f['testGroup/out'])
    f.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I run this script, I get the following output, so something has definitely been written, at least in memory.

```
HDF5 Data
<HDF5 dataset "bigData": shape (24, 6), type "<i4">
<HDF5 dataset "smallData": shape (8, 6), type "<i4">
<HDF5 dataset "out": shape (8, 6), type "<i4">
```

I get an HDF5 file in my directory of about 5kB.  However, when I open it with HDFView (version 2.11), I get a blank file.  Clicking on the Metadata tab at the bottom, I get the following, which appears to show nothing in the file:

```
/ (0)
    Group size = 0
    Number of attributes = 0
```

How do I get H5Py to actually write the file correctly?

Comment: This can be due to an incompatibility with HDFview. Try to reload with  h5py and check if all works fine.

Comment: Do you  have `h5dump` or other `h5` utilities installed?  I can read your file with that, or by opening the file in a new python script.  I have HDFView, but haven't used it much.

Comment: I too have problems viewing `h5py` files with `HDFView`, but not with `h5dump`.  My `h5py.version.hdf5_version_tuple` is (1,12,0), but `HDFView` 2.11, with version HDF5 1.10.4 (linux default source).

Comment: As noted above, it could be an incompatibly in HDF5 versions used by h5py  3.2 and HDFView 2.11. That version of HDFView is several years old. Test with the current version -- 3.1.2

Comment: I'm going to check out the software versions.  I didn't know that what was in the Ubuntu 20.04 repos was so old.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the comments by @hpaulj, I investigated the different versions.  The version of HDFView in the Ubuntu repository is so old that it isn't able to open the generated HDF5 file.  Switching to h5dump, I was able to verify the structure of my file was written correctly.